# Can you make a Set Theory definition of tuples that has limited depth?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

I was thinking about the set theory definitions of ordered pairs, such as $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$. And I think people usually add elements to make longer ordered tuples using the definition $(a,b,c)=((a,b),c)$; $(a,b,c,d)=((a,b,c),d)$; etc.

But by these definitions, as you make longer and longer ordered tuples, you get deeper and deeper sets representing them, like $(a,b)$ has depth $2$, $(a,b,c)$ has depth $4$, $(a,b,c,d)$ has depth $6$, etc. Is it possible to make definitions for ordered pairs and tuples so that all tuples' depths are less than a constant $M$?

I do not want to use any non-set elements. However, in that case, there's a limited number of possible sets with less than depth $M$, while there's an unlimited number of possible tuples.

Therefore, we will ignore the depth within a tuple's own elements and pretend that they have $0$ depth. Like if $a$ is a set that has depth $M+1$, that does not mean $(a,b)$'s set form will break the limit, because we will pretend $a$ has $0$ depth. However, if $a$ is used in $(b,c)$'s set form, then in that case $a$ will have $M+1$ depth and it will break the limit.

Comment: Isn't the depth of a $n$-tuple equal to $2(n-1)$? Therefore a tuple of depth at most $M$  is the same as a $n$-tuple with $n\le \frac{M}{2}-1$.

Comment: I'm looking for a definition such that there exists a constant $M$ where for all tuples, their depth is less than $M$.  So $M$ is the same for all tuples.

Comment: What about $(A,B,C,D)=\{A,\{A,B\},\{A,B,C\},\{A,B,C,D\}\}$? The only problem that I see here is that you may have undesired equalities between tuples of different lengths, e.g. $(A,A,A,A)=(A,A,A)$.

Comment: @Zuy yeah, it also has $(A,B,C,A)=(A,B,C,B)=(A,B,C,C)$.

Comment: That will have Difficulties with $(A,B,A,B)$ , @Zuy , where we have elements repeating.

Answer (score 1):

It is **impossible** to define ordered tuples in such a way so has to have bounded depth for all lengths. To see this note that there are finitely many depth-$M$ sets not using any variables (i.e. built solely from the empty set) and hence finitely many distinct ways to place a fixed finite number of "tuple element" sets into the depth-$M$ sets to obtain ordered tuples.

With sufficiently long tuples to make, there will not be enough depth-$M$ sets to represent all the ordered tuples (of unbounded length) using the given "tuple elements", even if there is only one "tuple element".

Comment: I am not completely sure if there are just exponentially many ways to make $M$-depth sets using the variables from the tuple.  For a set of n different variables, there are $n!$ n-long tuples.  There are $n$ 0-depth sets (just the variables themselves).  There are $n+2^n$ 1-depth or smaller sets.  There are $n+2^n+2^{n+2^n}$ 2-depth or smaller sets composed of the elements I think.  I think $f(n)=2^{(2^n)}$ already grows faster than factorials because it multiplies itself by 2, then 4, then 16, then 256, then 65536, etc.

Comment: Actually the number of 2-depth sets is wrong because it accidentally double counted the 1-depth sets.  It would be $n+2^{n+2^n}$.

Comment: @Xiutecuhtli Well... I had the idea before you.

Comment: I thought your message said number of possible sets increases exoponentially as length increases, while number of tuples increases at a faster factorial rate, so tuples would overtake sets. But iguess it is now edited to say finite sets vs infinite tuples, "even if there is only one tuple element" which is like exactly my answer now. I can click the "edited yesterday" under the answer to see what it used to say.

Answer (score 0):

**Can we use Natural Numbers ?**
We might have Natural Number using Non-Standard Constructions without Sets.

**If YES :**

We can theoretically make tuples with Sets having Constant Depth !

Here is such a Construction :

$ (A,B) = \{ \{1,\{A\}\} , \{2,\{B\}\} \}$
$ (A,B,C) = \{ \{1,\{A\}\} , \{2,\{B\}\} , \{3,\{C\}\} \}$
$ (A,B,C,D) = \{ \{1,\{A\}\} , \{2,\{B\}\} , \{3,\{C\}\} , \{4,\{D\}\} \}$
$ (A,B,C,D,E) = \{ \{1,\{A\}\} , \{2,\{B\}\} , \{3,\{C\}\} , \{4,\{D\}\} , \{5,\{E\}\} \}$

The tuples have Equivalent Sets with Constant Depth !

Is it Practical ? It is useful ? How make build up the whole theory with that ? How to show 2 tuples are Equivalent in formal Syntax ? What Difficulties will we encounter ?
These are out of scope of the Question & this Answer , I have merely given a theoretical Construction !

**If we can not use Natural Numbers & We want everything to be Sets :**

It is not Possible.
Various Proofs are given in Various Answers & Comments.

Here is my Proof of the Same , which may be somewhat Similar to the others :
Let there be some way to have Max Depth $M$.
Let X be the set of all tuples with 1 to $M$ elements.
Two elements/tuples ( $x_1$ , $x_2$ ) in X will have to Differ in at least 1 Place in the Set Structure.
Estimate all the Potential Places which can Differ for $x_1$ , $x_2$ (over counting is not a concern) : let that be a large Number Y. It can be Polynomial , Exponential , what-ever.
Make a new Set Z with all tuples with $Y+1$ elements , which Differ in all $Y+1$ Places.
Z will have elements which will not fit in the Set Structure with Max Depth $M$.
Z will have elements which require more than $M$ Depth.

Comment: The problem is that the natural numbers themselves don't have bounded depth, do they?

Comment: I'm trying to look for a definition that doesn't use any non-set elements.  And if the natural numbers are interpreted as sets, their depth increases unlimitedly.

Comment: I agree , that is Part of the "Difficulty" I was alluding to , @Zuy , though there are Alternative Constructions of Natural Numbers.

Comment: Correct , the Natural Numbers are non-set elements here , via Alternative Constructions , @Xiutecuhtli , where the Depth is Constant. If that is not Permitted , then (I think) , we might be able to Prove that there can be no way to achieve it.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to have no non-set elements.  And any set representation for natural numbers that makes them all distinct from each other and doesn't use the elements A,B,C,... will eventually run out of shallow sets and be forced to use deep sets that exceed the limit.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it is impossible. Consider tuples that are made of only the same element $a$ repeated $n$ times. There are an unlimited number of such tuples: $(a),(a,a),(a,a,a),(a,a,a,a),(a,a,a,a,a),...$ However, for any depth $M$, there is a limited number of sets that those tuples can translate to.

$M=0$: there is $1$ option: $a$

$M=1$: there are $1+2^1$ options: $a$, and sets containing none, some, or all of the 0-depth elements.

$M=2$: there are $1+2^{1+2^1}$ options: $a$, and sets containing none, some, or all of the 0- or 1-depth elements.

It continues like this, it will always be 1 + 2 ^ the previous row. Whatever finite number $M$ we use, we can only make finitely many sets but we need to be able to translate infinitely many tuples uniquely into them.